# System.Data.DataTable, DataRowCollection, and DataColumns: How does the indexing work?

Tags: c#, datatable, class-design

In a `DataTable`:

I can access all of the `DataRow` elements like so:

```
DataTable table = GetMyTable();
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++) {
  DataRow row = table.Rows[i];
  Console.WriteLine(row);
}
```

Also, I can access all of the `DataColumn` elements like this:

```
DataTable table = GetMyTable();
for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++) {
  DataColumn column = table.Columns[i];
  Console.WriteLine(column);
}
```

Finally, I can access each individual `Cell` of the `DataTable` object like this:

```
DataTable table = GetMyTable();
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++) {
  DataRow row = table.Rows[i];
  object[] array = row.ItemArray;
  for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++) {
    object cell = array[j];
    Console.WriteLine(cell);
  }
}
```

At least it looks like some information is lost in the third technique.

**Here's my question:**
*How is this array of objects being managed?*

I've been playing with how to recreate something with this basic type of functionality (since I am already familiar with it), but I just don't know how to design all these little sub-classes to make it work!

Comment: Please be more clear with your question. Do you really not understand having lists of an object that has a list property?

Comment: Hi John. No, there are obviously 2 lists here: A list of Rows and a list of Columns, but if I add a row, the Columns has to update and vice versa.

Comment: the table has a list of columns. This is a list of column definitions. The table has a list of rows. Each row has one cell for each column in the list of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table has a list of `DataColumn`. This is a list of column definitions. The table has a list of rows. Each row has one cell for each column in the list of columns.

---

The trick is that the rows are created by the table. The table knows the length of the `Columns` collection, as well as the data types of the columns and any constraints on them. When the table creates a `DataRow`, it creates it with the correct number of columns.

Comment: That seems to be the case. Somehow, though, the length of each row has to be fixed. What holds this fix? The table or the column collection? How would I create a row as some kind of `List<cells>` and lock the Length property of each row to the number of columns? Then, I have to be able to add and remove columns and get the ordinal for each column. Something I take for granted every day is very complex!

Comment: Thanks Mr. Saunders. I think the edit (added after the Horizontal Rule) explains why I wasn't able to figure out what was going on *under the hood* of the `DataTable` class.

Answer (score 3):

Making a simple class relationship isn't to difficult:

```
class Table
{
    public IEnumerable<Row> Rows { get; set; }
}
class Row
{
    public IEnumerable<Cell> Cells { get; set; }
}
class Cell { }
```

Comment: That seems pretty close, but how do the `DataColumn` objects fit into this? Would it be a separate collection within the `Row` class that is somehow only exposed through the `DataTable` object?

Comment: It would be an enumerable set in the table class if you want to match how the built in data sets work.

Answer (score 1):

It can be as simple as:

```
List<object[]> Rows {get; private set;}
```

Which lets you access it like:

```
obj[5][3]="meep.";
```

In the actual `DataTable`, `object[]` is wrapped in a `DataRow` class that provides access functions like `Field<>` and such, and `List<>` exposes a more limited amount of information to the outside through the `DataRowCollection` class.

Comment: Somehow, I need to maintain a collection of Header values for each column (that contains the Column Name and data type), force all rows to have the same number of elements, and if a column is added or removed, perform that on all row elements.